# What is Oracle error ORA-01536?

Tags: oracle

I got the following error on Oracle: ORA-01536

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Next time, I suggest you do two things before posting a question: Search the Oracle documentation at http://tahiti.oracle.com and post as much details about your problem as possible (DB and OS version, test code...).

Comment: wow 519 questions 0 answers.

Comment: shall we replicate the entire list of Oracle errors from the docs, or just leave it at this one?

Comment: @Jeffrey - Well, we have two so far: [i got this error on oracle: ORA-03134](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439245/i-got-this-error-on-oracle-ora-03134)

Comment: Why are people answering these questions. I can understand if this is the first time... I mean look at his questions and comments.... He does not care!!!!! He has not accepted answer for more than 200 questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The online documentation includes a book with explanations and resolutions for all the error messages.  Some of them are a bit cryptic but it is the place to start.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e1500.htm#sthref841).

Anyhoo, here is an illustrated solution for ORA-01536.

A DBA creates a new user:

```
SQL> create user fox_in_socks identified by tweetlebeetle
  2      default tablespace users quota 1M on users
  3  /

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to fox_in_socks
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

In another session our brave user creates a table...

```
SQL> conn fox_in_socks/tweetlebeetle
Connected.
SQL> create table t23 (col1 varchar2(4000))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL>
```

.. and does some work....

```
SQL> begin
  2      for i in 1..1000 loop
  3          insert into t23 values (rpad('a', 4000, 'a'));
  4          commit;
  5      end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'USERS'
ORA-06512: at line 3


SQL>
```

Uh-oh!  So our user goes to their tame DBA and asks for more quota, which they get:

```
SQL> alter user fox_in_socks
  2      quota 10M on users
  3  /

User altered.

SQL>
```

Work proceeds:

```
SQL> begin
  2      for i in 1..1000 loop
  3          insert into t23 values (rpad('a', 4000, 'a'));
  4          commit;
  5      end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If the user were an application owner then the DBA could have decided to give them unlimited quota (especially if they were the only user with privileges on that tablespace):

```
alter user fox_in_socks
    quota unlimited on users
/
```

(in real life this situation is unlikely to be true for the USERS tablespace).

Users can check their current quota using the appropriate view:

```
SQL> select * from user_ts_quotas
  2  /

TABLESPACE_NAME                     BYTES  MAX_BYTES     BLOCKS MAX_BLOCKS DRO
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
USERS                             9437184   10485760       1152       1280 NO

SQL>
```

Answer (score 6):

## ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'string'

**Cause**:  The space quota for the segment owner in the tablespace has been exhausted and the operation attempted the creation of a new segment extent in the tablespace.

**Action**:  Either drop unnecessary objects in the tablespace to reclaim space or have a privileged user increase the quota on this tablespace for the segment owner.